# inheritance via javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

i've been experimenting with javascript's prototypal inheritance and have come across something that perhaps can be explained.

```
function dinner(food,drink){
   this.food=food;
   this.drink=drink;

}
dinner.prototype.desert=function(){
var x = this.food;

return x.split(' ')[0]+' Ice Cream Float';
}
function superSupper(steak){
    this.steak=steak;
}
superSupper.prototype= new dinner();
superSupper.prototype.constructor=superSupper;
var x = new superSupper('corn','beet juice')
x.grub='beef';
x.clams = 'nope';
```

in the above code i'm making a new construtor "superSupper" and making it inherit from dinner. when this is viewed in a console.log i see this:

```
superSupper
clams: "nope"
grub: "beef"
steak: "corn"
__proto__: dinner
constructor: function superSupper(steak){
drink: undefined
food: undefined
__proto__: dinner
```

how do i access the drink and food properties that i have now inherited from dinner?

p.s. trying this: "x.food='some string'" only creates a new property in the superSupper instance called food, but does not assign a value to the inherited food property.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but changing the inherited property means that *all* `superSupper` instances will have that property set, since the inherited `dinner` instance is shared.

Comment: what im trying to do is access/assign the inherited properties in otherwords give them a value for this instance. i've tried alot to do this but they still remain undefined

Comment: @pimvdb from how i'm reading it, I think he wants to be able to access superSupper.food because superSupper "extends" dinner

Comment: @code wombat: Still I think that's not what you want. The `dinner` instance you created is set as the prototype of `superSupper`, so if you set a property on that `dinner` instance, **all** `superSupper` instances will have that property set. If you want to set it on a per-`superSupper`-instance basis then I don't think you want to alter the inherited property.

Comment: Yes, that's the same as for classes. Once property is defined in parent class, it could not be removed from child one. `hasOwnProperty` allows to distinguish, is property defined in certain instance, or one of its prototypes.

Comment: @codewombat i think the problem lies in how you're connecting the two classes using prototype = new dinner(), and prototype.constructor=superSupper. i'm going to research that a little

Comment: maybe im confused,but i thought that in normal inheritance if the original class had properties then the inheriting class would gain those properties and those properties would then become unique to that class instance(like a copy) that way you could play doctor on the inherited properties while not overriding the originals...im i missing something?

Comment: @pimvdb so inherited property really means inherited data? so the variable that the data was assigned to is just its reference name for which it is delivered to the inheriting class instance and instead is not a variable/property that can be overridden like a had previously assumed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to modify your `superSupper` a bit:

```
function superSupper(steak){
    // calling superclass constructor
    dinner.apply(this, arguments);
    this.steak=steak;
}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't matter here, you would usually want to call the "superclass" *before* setting own properties (in case you're overwriting properties).

Comment: so is apply moving the inherited properties into the scope of the instantiated object?

Comment: @codewombat you may want to read this: http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

Comment: `apply` and `call` can be used to execute a function in the scope of another object. So here dinner will be executed in the scope of superSupper, hence `this` inside dinner at this point refers to superSupper and food and dinner becomes property of superSupper

Comment: @Alex Pakka thanks for the link. i got a feeling that i should study classical inheritance as well

Comment: @Nemoy so from what i can see it seems like in js when you inherit a property you have access to the data that was assigned to it,but cannot override it's assignment(i.e. if it was an array in the superclass then it will always be an array or if it was a string then it will always be a string & will aways equal that string)

Comment: so i would have to assign it to a new variable: this.newFood = this.food

Comment: No you don't have to assign it to a new variable, you can override the existing properties to any type